# Create floating window application on Android C# MAUI?

Tags: maui

I'm quite new on Android, specifically I approach Android from C# MVVM MAUI. I tried Googling a lot but didn't get the exact answer and I also don't know what the name of that feature is...

I want to create an Android 14 application. Basically the application will have 2 states (Full screen and Floating window when I use the slide action from the Home key up..)
To be more specific, I used this feature from the Xiaomi Redmi Note 12 Global 4G Non-NFC phone with XiaomiHyperOS 1.0.2, Adnroid 14.

This is a photo/Video app when I open it it runs in Full Screen mode.
[image: Full Screen Mode]

When I slide the Home key up from the bottom it appears as a floating window.
[image: Floating Windows Mode]

Link to Video Example: https://mega.nz/file/fkdy1TyT#rZ4OEeIKSOB1Jq7AXByJcBoaPpokA3uwSedZ7aTG604

I hope you can point me in the right direction to make an application that can Floating Windows on (Android C# MVVM MAUI). I'm also using .Net8

Comment: Your instructions work fine in MAUI .NET 8. But I still don't understand it enough to customize in my app. It would be helpful if you took some time to share a video with detailed step-by-step instructions on YouTube so I can take advantage of the Auto Translate feature to understand. Or the documentation about this FloatingWindows feature. In this Video, the Facebook application can run in FloatingWindows mode: https://mega.nz/file/fkdy1TyT#rZ4OEeIKSOB1Jq7AXByJcBoaPpokA3uwSedZ7aTG604

Comment: *But I still don't understand it enough to customize in my app.* Just modify `floatview.xml` ,  to customize the layout, style or content you want.  `layoutParams.Width = 800;  layoutParams.Height = 600;` of  `FloatingService.cs` can determine FloatingWindow size.

Comment: " How to achieve it: FloatingWindow ? " In short, it uses [Android's Service](https://developer.android.com/develop/background-work/services).

Comment: If the reply is helpful, please do not forget to accept it as answer( click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For MAUI Android, you can use the following code:

Create a `Layout` floder and add floatview.xml into it([File structure](https://imgur.com/a/mFek2QM)), remeber to set its Build Action to `AndroidResource`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv1"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_play"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv2"
    android:src="@android:drawable/star_on"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv3"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_more"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

FloatingService.cs:

```cs
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using static Android.Views.View;
using Color = Android.Graphics.Color;
using View = Android.Views.View;


namespace MAUISample.Platforms.Android
{
    [Service]
    public class FloatingService : Service, IOnTouchListener
    {
        WindowManagerLayoutParams layoutParams;
        IWindowManager windowManager;
        View floatView;
        
        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            base.OnCreate();
        }


       public override bool OnUnbind(Intent? intent)
        {
            return base.OnUnbind(intent);
        }


       [return: GeneratedEnum]
        public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, [GeneratedEnum] StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
        {
            showFloatingWindow();
            return StartCommandResult.NotSticky;
        }


       private void showFloatingWindow()
        {
            windowManager = GetSystemService(WindowService).JavaCast<IWindowManager>();
            LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.From(ApplicationContext);
            floatView = mLayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.floatview, null);
            floatView.SetBackgroundColor(Color.RoyalBlue);
            floatView.SetOnTouchListener(this);
            ImageView iv1 = floatView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.iv1);
            ImageView iv2 = floatView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.iv2);
            ImageView iv3 = floatView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.iv3);
            iv1.Click += delegate { Toast.MakeText(ApplicationContext, "The first Image Click", ToastLength.Short).Show(); };
            iv2.Click += delegate { Toast.MakeText(ApplicationContext, "The second Image Click", ToastLength.Short).Show(); };
            iv3.Click += delegate { Toast.MakeText(ApplicationContext, "The third Image Click", ToastLength.Short).Show(); };


           // set LayoutParam
            layoutParams = new WindowManagerLayoutParams();
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
            {
                layoutParams.Type = WindowManagerTypes.ApplicationOverlay;
            }
            else
            {
                layoutParams.Type = WindowManagerTypes.Phone;
            }
            layoutParams.Flags = WindowManagerFlags.NotTouchModal;
            layoutParams.Flags = WindowManagerFlags.NotFocusable;


           layoutParams.Width = 800;
            layoutParams.Height = 600;
            layoutParams.X = 300;
            layoutParams.Y = 300;
            windowManager.AddView(floatView, layoutParams);


       }
        private int x;
        private int y;
        public bool OnTouch(global::Android.Views.View? v, MotionEvent? e)
        {
            switch (e.Action)
            {


               case MotionEventActions.Down:
                    x = (int)e.RawX;
                    y = (int)e.RawY;
                    break;


               case MotionEventActions.Move:
                    int nowX = (int)e.RawX;
                    int nowY = (int)e.RawY;
                    int movedX = nowX - x;
                    int movedY = nowY - y;
                    x = nowX;
                    y = nowY;
                    layoutParams.X = layoutParams.X + movedX;
                    layoutParams.Y = layoutParams.Y + movedY;


                    windowManager.UpdateViewLayout(floatView, layoutParams);
                    break;


               default:
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }

       public override IBinder? OnBind(Intent? intent)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

   }
}
```

MainActivity.cs:

```cs
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Provider;
using Android.Runtime;
using MAUISample.Platforms.Android;


namespace MAUISample
{
    [Activity(Theme = "@style/Maui.SplashTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Density)]
    public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
    {
        Intent intent;
        
        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            intent = new Intent(this, typeof(FloatingService));


           if (!Settings.CanDrawOverlays(this))
            {
                StartActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ActionManageOverlayPermission, Android.Net.Uri.Parse("package:" + PackageName)), 0);
            }
            else
            {
                StartService(intent);
            }
            base.OnStop();
        }
        
        protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            if (requestCode == 0)
            {
                if (!Settings.CanDrawOverlays(this))
                {


               }
                else
                {
                    StartService(new Intent(this, typeof(FloatingService)));
                }
            }
        }

   }
}
```

Add this to your `AndroidManifext`:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```